# Verilog Image Filter

Tags: verilog

I've been playing around in verilog trying to implement a little image filter that adds a blur effect, mirrors an image, or rotates it 90*. I'm pretty new to this stuff so please bear with me.
I've noticed while running simulations that the registers have a big delay before they change to their new values, this has cause some problems for me so far. I've managed to get mirroring and rotation to work, then added the blur filter. Now it won't work anymore for some odd reason, even after removing the new added code. It keeps showing me that the output are X...
 I'm using a 64x64 grayscale image, and doing some simple matrix operations. Still i can't seem to get to work properly, the blur filter specifically, and now i have this mysterious all outputs are X while in simulation mode for some reason.

Here is the code for the process:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module process(
    input clk,                      // clock 
    input [1:0] op,                 // 0 - filtrul de tip blur; 1 - oglindire; 2 - rotire
    input [7:0] in_pix,             // valaorea pixelului de pe pozitia [in_row, in_col] din imaginea de intrare
    output reg [5:0] in_row, in_col,    // selecteaza un rand si o coloana din imaginea de intrare 
    output reg [5:0] out_row, out_col,  // selecteaza un rand si o coloana din imaginea de iesire
    output reg out_we,                  // activeaza scrierea pentru imaginea de iesire (write enable)
    output reg [7:0] out_pix,           // valoarea pixelului care va fi scrisa in imaginea de iesire pe pozitia [out_row, out_col]
    output  reg done                        // semnaleaza cand s-a terminat procesarea unei imagini
    );  

// TODO add your finite state machines here

`define INIT 3'b000
`define MOVE_PIXEL 3'b001
`define INC_INDEX 3'b010
`define DONE 3'b011
`define DIVISION 3'b100

    reg [6:0] index_col,index_row,index1_col,index1_row; // indicatori cu care se parcurg matricea imagine pentru input si output.
    reg [2:0] state; // registru de stare pentru automate
    reg [7:0] pixel; // registru in care stocam valoarea de pixel pentru intrare si iesire
    reg [7:0] pixel_q; // registru folosit pentru memorarea catului la impartirea prin 5.
    reg [10:0] sum; // folosit pentru insumarea pixelilor vecini dupa care este inmultita cu 0.2 pentru a face sum/5. este pe 11 biti deoarece 255*5 este 1275, deci 2^11 = 2048 ca sa nu avem overflow
    reg [3:0] timer; // timer pentru sincronizarea datelor , am ales sa astept 6 ciclii pentru realizarea sincronizarii
    always@(posedge clk) begin

    /*if(op == 0) begin                                         // Pentru marginile imaginii am decis sa fac cazuri speciale
            state <= `INIT;                                 // astfel adun doar elementele care exista langa pixelul curent
                                                                    // de exemplu in coltul 0.0 avem elemente doar la 0.1 si 1.0.
            case(state)                                         

            `INIT: begin
                index_row   <= 0;               
                index_col   <= 0;
                done            <= 0;
                timer           <= 0;
                pixel_q     <= 0;
                state       <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end
            `MOVE_PIXEL: begin
                sum     <= 0;
                in_row  <= index_row;
                in_col  <= index_col;
                pixel   <= in_pix;
                if(timer < 6) begin
                    timer <= timer + 1;
                    state <=`MOVE_PIXEL;
                end else begin
                sum <= sum + pixel;
                if(index_row == 0 && index_col == 0) begin // cazuri speciale: colturile si marginile; coltul 0.0
                    in_row  <= index_row + 1; 
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else if (index_row == 0 && index_col == 63) begin // coltul 0.63
                    in_row  <= index_row + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else if(index_row == 63 && index_col == 0) begin //coltul 63.0
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row + 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else if(index_row == 63 && index_col == 63) begin // coltul 63.63
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row + 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else if(in_row == 0 && in_col > 0) begin // marginea de sus
                    in_row  <= index_row + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 2;
                    pixel       <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;


                end else if(in_col == 0 && in_row > 0) begin // marginea din stanga
                    in_row  <= index_row + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel       <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_row + 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else if(in_row == 63 && in_col > 0) begin //marginea de jos
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row + 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 2;
                    pixel       <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else if(in_col == 63 && in_row > 0) begin // marginea din dreapta
                    in_row  <= index_row + 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;
                    in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel       <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_row + 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                end else begin //interiorul matricii                                //          0                   (index_row -1).index_col         0
                    in_row  <= index_row + 1;                                               // index_row.(index_col - 1) index_row.index_col index_row.(index_col + 1)
                    pixel   <= in_pix;                                                  //              0                   (index_row + 1).index_col         0
                    sum         <= sum + pixel;                                         //          Structura in care sunt alesi pixelii pentru blur.
                    in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel       <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + pixel;
                    in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    in_row  <= index_row - 1;
                    pixel   <= in_pix;
                    sum     <= sum + in_pix;
    //              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                    in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                    state   <= `DIVISION;

                    out_row     <= index_row;
                    out_col     <= index_col;
                    out_we  <= 1;
                    out_pix     <= pixel;
                    state   <= `INC_INDEX; 
                 end
              end
            end
            `DIVISION: begin
                if(sum >= 5) begin
                sum <= sum - 5;
                pixel_q <= pixel_q + 1;
                state <= `DIVISION;
                end else begin
                    out_row     <= index_row;
                    out_col     <= index_col;
                    out_we  <= 1;
                    out_pix     <= pixel_q;
                    state   <= `INC_INDEX;
                end
            end
            `INC_INDEX: begin
                index_col  <= index_col + 1;
                if( index_col == 63 ) begin
                    index_row  <= index_row + 1;
                    state     <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
                end else if (index_row == 63 && index1_row == 63) begin
                        state <= `DONE;
                end else begin
                state <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
                end
            end
            `DONE: begin
            done <= 1;
            state <= `INIT;
            end
            endcase
            end */



    if(op == 1) begin               // pixelii sunt inversati ca pozitie, pixelii din prima coloana trec in ultima si invers, procedeul se repeta secvential.
            state <= `INIT;

            case(state)

            `INIT: begin
                index_row   <= 0;
                index_col   <= 0;
                index1_row  <= 0;
                index1_col  <= 63;
    //          timer       <= 0;
                done <= 0;
                state       <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end
            `MOVE_PIXEL: begin
                in_row  <= index1_row;
                in_col  <= index1_col;
                pixel   <= in_pix;
    //          if(timer < 6) begin
    //              timer <= timer + 1;
    //              state <=`MOVE_PIXEL;
    //          end else begin
                out_row     <= index_row;
                out_col     <= index_col;
                out_we  <= 1;
                out_pix     <= pixel;
                out_we  <= 0;
                state   <= `INC_INDEX;
    //          end
            end
            `INC_INDEX: begin
                index_col  <= index_col + 1;
                index1_col <= index1_col - 1;
                if( index_col == 63 && index1_col == 0) begin
                    index_row  <= index_row + 1;
                    index1_row <= index1_row +1;
                    state     <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
                end else if (index_row == 63 && index1_row == 63) begin
                        state <= `DONE;
                end else begin
                state <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
                end
            end
            `DONE: begin
            done <= 1;
            state <= `INIT;
            end
            endcase
            end

    if(op == 2) begin               // liniile devine coloane, se incepe de la ultima linie care se scrie ca prima coloana si se repeta procedeul.
            state <= `INIT;

            case(state)

            `INIT: begin
                index_row   <= 0;
                index_col   <= 0;
                index1_row  <= 63;
                index1_col  <= 0;
        //      timer       <= 0;
                done <= 0;
                state       <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end
            `MOVE_PIXEL: begin
                in_row  <= index1_row;
                in_col  <= index1_col;
                pixel   <= in_pix;
        //      if(timer < 6) begin
        //          timer <= timer + 1;
        //          state <=`MOVE_PIXEL;
        //      end else begin
                out_row     <= index_row;
                out_col     <= index_col;
                out_we  <= 1;
                out_pix     <= pixel;
                out_we  <= 0;
                state   <= `INC_INDEX;
        //      end
            end
            `INC_INDEX: begin
                index_row <= index_row + 1;
                index1_col <= index1_col + 1;

                if( index_row == 63 && index1_col == 63) begin
                    index_col  <= index_col + 1;
                    index1_row <= index1_row - 1;
                    state     <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
                end else if (index_col == 63 && index1_row == 0) begin
                        state <= `DONE;
                end else begin
                state <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
                end
            end
            `DONE: begin
            done <= 1;
            state <= `INIT;
            end
            endcase     
            end

    end     

    endmodule
```

It interacts with an image module:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module image(
    input clk,          // clock 
    input[5:0] row,     // selecteaza un rand din imagine
    input[5:0] col,     // selecteaza o coloana din imagine
    input we,           // write enable (activeaza scrierea in imagine la randul si coloana date)
    input[7:0] in,      // valoarea pixelului care va fi scris pe pozitia data
    output[7:0] out     // valoarea pixelului care va fi citit de pe pozitia data
    );

reg[7:0]  data[63:0][63:0];

assign out = data[row][col];

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(we)
        data[row][col] <= in;
end

endmodule
```

Could anyone give me any help ? I apologize if my question is in the incorrect format, first time posting here.

LE: I've redesigned the state machine for the blur filter but i'm getting some odd warnings. For instance it says for Timer_3 (i assume its talking about timer from the third FSM which handles rotation) "FF/Latch  (without init value) has a constant value of 0 in block . This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process." 
And this one as well " Signal  is assigned but never used. This unconnected signal will be trimmed during the optimization process." I don't get it how is it not used? I clearly use it to go to INIT_BLUR and from there to CURRENT_PIXEL.

```
  `timescale 1ns / 1ps

module process(
    input clk,                      // clock 
    input [1:0] op,                 // 0 - filtrul de tip blur; 1 - oglindire; 2 - rotire
    input [7:0] in_pix,             // valaorea pixelului de pe pozitia [in_row, in_col] din imaginea de intrare
    output reg [5:0] in_row, in_col,    // selecteaza un rand si o coloana din imaginea de intrare 
    output reg [5:0] out_row, out_col,  // selecteaza un rand si o coloana din imaginea de iesire
    output reg out_we,                  // activeaza scrierea pentru imaginea de iesire (write enable)
    output reg [7:0] out_pix,           // valoarea pixelului care va fi scrisa in imaginea de iesire pe pozitia [out_row, out_col]
    output  reg done                        // semnaleaza cand s-a terminat procesarea unei imagini
    );  

// TODO add your finite state machines here

`define INIT_BLUR           4'b0000
`define CURRENT_PIXEL       4'b0001
`define TOP_PIXEL           4'b0010
`define BOTTOM_PIXEL        4'b0011
`define LEFT_PIXEL          4'b0100
`define RIGHT_PIXEL             4'b0101
`define DIVISION                4'b0110
`define INC_INDEX_BLUR      4'b0111
`define DONE_BLUR           4'b1000

`define INIT            3'b000
`define MOVE_PIXEL  3'b001
`define INC_INDEX   3'b010
`define DONE            3'b011

reg [6:0] index_col,index_row,index1_col,index1_row; // indicatori cu care se parcurg matricea imagine pentru input si output.
reg [2:0] state; // registru de stare pentru automate
reg [3:0] blur_states;
reg [7:0] pixel; // registru in care stocam valoarea de pixel pentru intrare si iesire
reg [7:0] pixel_q; // registru folosit pentru memorarea catului la impartirea prin 5.
reg [10:0] sum; // folosit pentru insumarea pixelilor vecini dupa care este inmultita cu 0.2 pentru a face sum/5. este pe 11 biti deoarece 255*5 este 1275, deci 2^11 = 2048 ca sa nu avem overflow
reg [3:0] timer; // timer pentru sincronizarea datelor , am ales sa astept 6 ciclii pentru realizarea sincronizarii
always@(posedge clk) begin

if(op == 0) begin                                           // Pentru marginile imaginii am decis sa fac cazuri speciale
        blur_states <= `INIT_BLUR;                                  // astfel adun doar elementele care exista langa pixelul curent
                                                                // de exemplu in coltul 0.0 avem elemente doar la 0.1 si 1.0.
        case(state)                                         

        `INIT_BLUR: begin
            index_row   <= 0;               
            index_col   <= 0;
            index1_row  <= 0;
            index1_col  <= 0;
            done            <= 0;
            timer           <= 0;
            pixel_q     <= 0;
            state       <= `CURRENT_PIXEL;
        end
        `CURRENT_PIXEL: begin
            sum     <= 0;
            in_row  <= index_row;
            in_col  <= index_col;
            pixel   <= in_pix;  
            sum          <= sum + pixel;
            if(timer < 6) begin
                timer <= timer + 1;
                state <=`CURRENT_PIXEL;
            end else begin
            if(index_row == 0 && index_col == 0) begin // cazuri speciale: colturile si marginile; coltul 0.0
                blur_states <= `RIGHT_PIXEL;            
            end else if (index_row == 0 && index_col == 63) begin // coltul 0.63
                blur_states <= `BOTTOM_PIXEL;
            end else if(in_row == 0 && in_col > 0) begin // marginea de sus
                blur_states <= `RIGHT_PIXEL;                        
            end else begin //interiorul matricii            
                blur_states <= `TOP_PIXEL;

                                                                                            //          0                   (index_row -1).index_col         0
//              in_row  <= index_row + 1;                                           // index_row.(index_col - 1) index_row.index_col index_row.(index_col + 1)
//              pixel   <= in_pix;                                                  //              0                   (index_row + 1).index_col         0
//              sum         <= sum + pixel;                                         //          Structura in care sunt alesi pixelii pentru blur.
//              in_row   <= index_row - 1;
//              in_col  <= index_col - 1;
//              pixel   <= in_pix;
//              sum     <= sum + pixel;
//              in_col  <= index_col + 1;
//              in_row  <= index_row - 1;
//              pixel       <= in_pix;
//              sum     <= sum + pixel;
//              in_col  <= index_col + 1;
//              in_row  <= index_row - 1;
//              pixel   <= in_pix;
//              sum     <= sum + in_pix;
//              sum     <= sum * 0.2;
//              in_col  <= index_col - 1;
//              state   <= `DIVISION;
/*              
                out_row     <= index_row;
                out_col     <= index_col;
                out_we  <= 1;
                out_pix     <= pixel;
                state   <= `INC_INDEX;  */
             end
          end
        end
         `TOP_PIXEL: begin
            index1_row  <= index_row + 1;
            index1_col  <= index_col;
            pixel       <= in_pix;
            sum             <= sum + pixel;
         if( index_col == 63 && index_row == 63) begin
             blur_states <= `LEFT_PIXEL;
         end else if( index_col == 63) begin
             blur_states <= `BOTTOM_PIXEL;
        end else begin
             blur_states <= `RIGHT_PIXEL;
         end
        end
         `RIGHT_PIXEL: begin
            index1_row  <= index_row;
            index1_col  <= index_col + 1;
            pixel           <= in_pix;
            sum         <= sum + pixel;
          if( index_row == 63 && index_col == 0) begin
            blur_states <= `DIVISION;
          end else if(index_row == 63) begin
           blur_states <= `LEFT_PIXEL;
          end else begin
           blur_states <= `BOTTOM_PIXEL;
          end
        end
         `BOTTOM_PIXEL: begin
            index1_row <= index_row - 1;
            index1_col <= index_col;
            pixel     <= in_pix;
            sum       <= sum + pixel;
           if (index_col == 0) begin
            blur_states <= `DIVISION;   
           end else begin
            blur_states <= `LEFT_PIXEL;
            end
        end
         `LEFT_PIXEL: begin
            index1_row <= index_row;
            index1_col <= index_col - 1;
            pixel     <= in_pix;
            sum           <= sum + pixel;
            blur_states<= `DIVISION;
        end
        `DIVISION: begin
            if(sum >= 5) begin
            sum <= sum - 5;
            pixel_q <= pixel_q + 1;
            state <= `DIVISION;
            end else begin
                out_row     <= index_row;
                out_col     <= index_col;
                out_we  <= 1;
                out_pix     <= pixel_q;
                state   <= `INC_INDEX;
            end
        end
        `INC_INDEX_BLUR: begin
            out_we    <= 0;
            index_col  <= index_col + 1;
            if( index_col == 63 ) begin
                index_row  <= index_row + 1;
                state     <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end else if (index_row == 63 && index1_row == 63) begin
                    state <= `DONE;
            end else begin
            state <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end
        end
        `DONE_BLUR: begin
        done <= 1;
        state <= `INIT_BLUR;
        end
        endcase
        end


if(op == 1) begin               // pixelii sunt inversati ca pozitie, pixelii din prima coloana trec in ultima si invers, procedeul se repeta secvential.
        state <= `INIT;

        case(state)

        `INIT: begin
            index_row   <= 0;
            index_col   <= 0;
            index1_row  <= 0;
            index1_col  <= 63;
            timer       <= 0;
            done <= 0;
            state       <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
        end
        `MOVE_PIXEL: begin
            in_row  <= index1_row;
            in_col  <= index1_col;
            pixel   <= in_pix;
            if(timer < 6) begin
                timer <= timer + 1;
                state <=`MOVE_PIXEL;
            end else begin
            out_row     <= index_row;
            out_col     <= index_col;
            out_we  <= 1;
            out_pix     <= pixel;
            out_we  <= 0;
            state   <= `INC_INDEX;
            end
        end
        `INC_INDEX: begin
            index_col  <= index_col + 1;
            index1_col <= index1_col - 1;
            if( index_col == 63 && index1_col == 0) begin
                index_row  <= index_row + 1;
                index1_row <= index1_row +1;
                state     <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end else if (index_row == 63 && index1_row == 63) begin
                    state <= `DONE;
            end else begin
            state <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end
        end
        `DONE: begin
        done <= 1;
        state <= `INIT;
        end
        endcase
        end

if(op == 2) begin               // liniile devine coloane, se incepe de la ultima linie care se scrie ca prima coloana si se repeta procedeul.
        state <= `INIT;

        case(state)

        `INIT: begin
            index_row   <= 0;
            index_col   <= 0;
            index1_row  <= 63;
            index1_col  <= 0;
            timer       <= 0;
            done <= 0;
            state       <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
        end
        `MOVE_PIXEL: begin
            in_row  <= index1_row;
            in_col  <= index1_col;
            pixel   <= in_pix;
            if(timer < 6) begin
                timer <= timer + 1;
                state <=`MOVE_PIXEL;
            end else begin
            out_row     <= index_row;
            out_col     <= index_col;
            out_we  <= 1;
            out_pix     <= pixel;
            out_we  <= 0;
            state   <= `INC_INDEX;
            end
        end
        `INC_INDEX: begin
            index_row <= index_row + 1;
            index1_col <= index1_col + 1;

            if( index_row == 63 && index1_col == 63) begin
                index_col  <= index_col + 1;
                index1_row <= index1_row - 1;
                state     <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end else if (index_col == 63 && index1_row == 0) begin
                    state <= `DONE;
            end else begin
            state <= `MOVE_PIXEL;
            end
        end
        `DONE: begin
        done <= 1;
        state <= `INIT;
        end
        endcase     
        end

end     

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to say, but I think you're still conceptually far from a solution, and not really understanding how verilog works.

Taking for an example this small snippet of code:

```
            if(index_row == 0 && index_col == 0) begin
                in_row  <= index_row + 1; 
                pixel   <= in_pix;
                sum         <= sum + pixel;
                in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                in_col  <= index_col + 1;
                pixel   <= in_pix;
                sum     <= sum + pixel;
                sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                state   <= `DIVISION;
```

This looks as if you took a C algorithm and assumed that you can just replicate it in verilog, but verilog does not work this way. You need to understand that all 10 assignments you have here happen **at the same time**. That means that you're simultaneously assigning `sum <= sum + pixel`, `sum <= sum - pixel`, and `sum <= sum * 0.2`. The last assignment wins, and the earlier statements are effectively discarded.

Understanding this, looking at your algorithm, many of the statements have no effect, and your code effectively reduces to this:

```
            if(index_row == 0 && index_col == 0) begin
                ------------------------ 
                ------------------------
                ------------------------
                in_row   <= index_row - 1;
                ------------------------
                pixel   <= in_pix;
                ------------------------
                sum     <= sum * 0.2;
                in_col  <= index_col - 1;
                state   <= `DIVISION;
```

So it's no surprise that it doesn't work the way you expect. In general, if you have 10 'C-like' statements that you want to execute in sequence, then you need a 10 stage state machine, and execute one state each clock.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point, well what if I used blocking assignments instead non blocking? Or could you recommend another way to make it? As it stands I've kinda hit a brick wall at the moment.

Comment: If you used blocking statements, it might work a little bit more conceptually how you expect, although your timing paths would be so long that it would be difficult to synthesize with any decent clock speed. (you'd have a combinatorial path of dozens of adds/multiplies in a single clock cycle). What you're trying to do is a pretty significant project, and I think it would help if you tried to start with something conceptually simpler to better learn verilog first.